# Access dictionary inside nested list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
[[{'id': 1772391,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'PERSON',
   'start_offset': 44,
   'end_offset': 52,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772397,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'PERSON',
   'start_offset': 150,
   'end_offset': 169,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772405,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'PERSON',
   'start_offset': 217,
   'end_offset': 226,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772387,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'TITLE',
   'start_offset': 0,
   'end_offset': 21,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772389,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'TITLE',
   'start_offset': 22,
   'end_offset': 39,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772400,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'TITLE',
   'start_offset': 189,
   'end_offset': 203,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772403,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'TITLE',
   'start_offset': 204,
   'end_offset': 216,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772408,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'FACILITY',
   'start_offset': 285,
   'end_offset': 310,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772396,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'ORG',
   'start_offset': 138,
   'end_offset': 150,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501},
  {'id': 1772410,
   'prob': 0.8,
   'label': 'LOC',
   'start_offset': 312,
   'end_offset': 329,
   'user': 15,
   'document': 1062501}]]
```

The only one list inside of list.
I try to access the start_offset, and end_offset inside of the list.
How to access them?
I tried this code :

```
[annotation[i][j]['end_offset'] for i,j in annotation]
```

P.S : the annotation is the name of the nested list

Comment: "I tried this code :" What happeend when you tried that code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: "The only one list inside of list" Okay. Do you know how to write code that just gives you that single contained list? (Hint: it's an element of the containing list. What is its index? How do you get a single element from a list, if you know its index?) Once you get that list, can you write code to solve the rest of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean by:

```
>>> [{k: v for k, v in i.items() if k in ['start_offset', 'end_offset']} for x in annotation for i in x]
[{'start_offset': 44, 'end_offset': 52}, {'start_offset': 150, 'end_offset': 169}, {'start_offset': 217, 'end_offset': 226}, {'start_offset': 0, 'end_offset': 21}, {'start_offset': 22, 'end_offset': 39}, {'start_offset': 189, 'end_offset': 203}, {'start_offset': 204, 'end_offset': 216}, {'start_offset': 285, 'end_offset': 310}, {'start_offset': 138, 'end_offset': 150}, {'start_offset': 312, 'end_offset': 329}]
>>>
```

Comment: I tried to make a list of start_offset and end_offset instead of annotation[0]. I want it to be in all annotation

Comment: I want it to be in one list not apart

Comment: @zzzz Edited my answer should work now, please accept and upvote as well

Comment: It did, how can I keep the dict value from it tho?
Like {start_offset: 45, end_offset : 50 }

Comment: It is the value itself that is getting printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
lists = ([(i['start_offset'], i['end_offset']) for ele in annotation for i in ele])

start_offset = [i for i,j in lists]
end_offset= [j for i,j in lists]
```

Result:

```
print(start_offset)
[44, 150, 217, 0, 22, 189, 204, 285, 138, 312]

print(end_offset)
[52, 169, 226, 21, 39, 203, 216, 310, 150, 329]

# As a Single list
print(lists)
[(44, 52), (150, 169), (217, 226), (0, 21), (22, 39), (189, 203), (204, 216), (285, 310), (138, 150), (312, 329)]
```

This will work even if you have more than one list.

Comment: I want it to be as one list, sorry

Comment: Try `print`ing `lists` if you want a single lists. Do you want a list of tuples or a list of bare values

Answer (score 0):

for end offset:

```
final_list=[]
for item in annotation:
    for dict in item:
        final_list.append(dict['end_offset'])
print(final_list)
```

Output:

```
[52, 169, 226, 21, 39, 203, 216, 310, 150, 329]
```